# Create a SET product from simple product on the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product

Is there a way to add a simple product to a set of products in the cart?

For example, I want to make a beverage containing 4 bottles of wine. From the product page, I will add these bottles to a set. This Set will be a custom product.

Add another example:
I have a custom product A, I want to add products b1, b2, c1, c2 ... as an attribute or child product of product A. In Magento 1 is there a way to do this? Please advise me.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this could be done with [Grouped products](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-grouped.html)

Comment: If I use 5 or 10 simple product, in this case, It is fine. But if we have 1k bottles and We want to add any simple product to the Set. It is unavailable